# WebPack: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: angular, unit-testing, webpack, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

### WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

I am working Angular 6 Project:

Im am facing an error while running `ng test --code-coverage`. But it's working fine while running `ng test` and `ng serve` and `ng build`. I have tried to find to resolve this issue.

but I am unable to resolve this. Could you please resolve this?

**Detailed Error:**

```
ng test --code-coverage
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[14].include should be one of these:
   RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? } | [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
   -> One or multiple rule conditions
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[14].include should be an instance of RegExp
    * configuration.module.rules[14].include: The provided value "" is not an absolute path!
    * configuration.module.rules[14].include should be an instance of function
    * configuration.module.rules[14].include should be an array:
      [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
    * configuration.module.rules[14].include should be an object.
    * configuration.module.rules[14].include should be an array:
      [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
    at webpack (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:31:9)
    at init (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\packages\angular_devkit\build_angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\karma.ts:153:16)
    at Array.invoke (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
    at Injector.get (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:48:43)
    at config.frameworks.forEach (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:154:61)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Server._start (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:154:23)
    at Injector.invoke (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
    at Promise.all.then.then (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:127:24)
    at tryCatcher (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (D:\LTCProjects\AccessandWorkflow\UI\Dev\WorkFlow\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
```

Project detail:
[image]

Comment: Please add your webpack.config file and also the version

Comment: @TonyNgo I don't have `webpack.config` in my project. Where I need to see that file?

Comment: Can you take a screen shot how your project look like. So is your angular project ejcet the webpack file ?

Comment: @TonyNgo Updated in my question